# Remove multiple file extesions when using gnu parallel and cat in bash

Tags: bash, sed, cat, gnu-parallel

I have a csv file (separated by comma), which contains

```
file1a.extension.extension,file1b.extension.extension
file2a.extension.extension,file2b.extension.extension
```

Problem is, these files are name such as file.extension.extension

I'm trying to feed both columns to parallel and removing all extesions

I tried some variations of:

```
cat /home/filepairs.csv | sed 's/\..*//' | parallel --colsep ',' echo column 1 = {1}.extension.extension column 2 =  {2}
```

Which I expected to output

```
column 1 = file1a.extension.extension column 2 = file1b
column 1 = file2a.extension.extension column 2 = file2b
```

But outputs:

```
column 1 = file1a.extension.extension column 2 = 
column 1 = file2a.extension.extension column 2 =
```

The sed command is working but is feeding only column 1 to parallel

Comment: yes! It is feeding only {1} to parallel, not {2} but I'm not sure why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As currently written the `sed` only prints one name per line:

```
$ sed 's/\..*//'  filepairs.csv
file1a
file2a
```

Where:

- `\.` matches on first literal period (`.`)
- `.*` matches rest of line (ie, everything after the first literal period to the end of the line)
- `//` says to remove everything from the first literal period to the end of the line

I'm guessing what you really want is two names per line ... one `sed` idea:

```
$ sed 's/\.[^,]*//g'   filepairs.csv
file1a,file1b
file2a,filepath2b
```

Where:

- `\.` matches on first literal period (`.`)
- `[^,]*` matches on everything up to a comma (or end of line)
- `//g` says to remove the literal period, everything afterwards (up to a comma or end of line), and the `g` says to do it repeatedly (in this case the replacement occurs twice)

**NOTE:** I don't have `parallel` on my system so unable to test that portion of OP's code

Comment: I see! sed was reading the csv as one line of text, of course. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `--plus`:

```
$ cat filepairs.csv | parallel --plus --colsep , echo {1..} {2..}
file1a file1b
file2a file2b
```

If the input is CSV:

```
$ cat filepairs.csv | parallel --plus --csv echo {1..} {2..}
file1a file1b
file2a file2b
```